# FlexSlider - Thumbnail Navigation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I have the latest version installed. No console errors, correct markup, correct js configuration. This damn thing won't work though. You can check it out [here](https://www.mygadgeto.com/wpmig/index.php/gadget/httpswww-rosefieldwatches-comusthe-mercerwhite-rose-goldrose-gold/).

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  // The slider being synced must be initialized first
        jQuery('#image_gallery_carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 210,
        itemMargin: 5,
        asNavFor: '#image_gallery_slider'
      });

      jQuery('#image_gallery_slider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        sync: "#image_gallery_carousel"
      });
});
```